# NetBeans does not install properly

Tags: software-installation, software-center, netbeans

I'm trying to install NetBeans IDE on my Ubuntu 12.04. However no matter how many time i install/resintall it (from Software Center), it still gives this strange problem:

After I complete the installation and try to launch it, Netbeans first displays the initialization window. After it completes, the window disappears and nothing happens. Then after a while Netbeans seemingly restarts and then again shows the initialization window.

This goes on in a never-ending cycle and I'm ultimately forced to restart my computer and uninstall NetBeans.

Why could this be happening? I really need NetBeans as it is a very good IDE.

Comment: Have you tried installing from terminal?

Comment: Good idea. I'll try and post the result.

Comment: Tried it with terminal. Same result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi have you tried installing it manually I usually install Netbeans on my different work stations manually to take advantage of the latest releases.

- [Versions available](http://netbeans.org/downloads/index.html)
- [Release notes](http://netbeans.org/community/releases/71/relnotes.html)
- [Install instructions](http://netbeans.org/community/releases/71/install.html)

I have also include a link to a video below that I used although it's a bit old it's still very good.

[Video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XwAHLWTQ4eE)

Comment: Cool, I'm a big fan of Netbeans so I'm glad you got it working!

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you are using the official JDK, provided by Oracle, not the OpenJDK, which comes with Ubuntu by default. Eclipse does not work very well with the OpenJDK - I would suspect this might be the case with Netbeans as well.
To check your Java version, open the terminal and try this:

```
java -version
```

You should see something like this:

```
java version "1.7.0_03"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_03-b04)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 22.1-b02, mixed mode)
```

instead of this:

```
java version "1.7.0_03"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea7 2.1.1pre) (7~u3-2.1.1~pre1-1ubuntu3)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 22.0-b10, mixed mode)
```